# Swift issue with WKWebView and Keyboard appearance LayoutConstraints error

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, wkwebview, uikeyboard

building app with `WKWebView`, in HTML I have a input text field, when I focus on textfield keyboard pops up and getting `LayoutConstraints` errors,
can't figure out how to solve my issue.

My simple implementation:

```
class  WebViewBase: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let web = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        web.uiDelegate = self
        web.navigationDelegate = self
        return web
    }()

    lazy var webViewCont:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }()

    lazy var navBarHeight:CGFloat = {

        guard let navbar = self.navigationController else {
            return 64
        }

        return navbar.navigationBar.frame.size.height
    }()

    let screenSize:CGRect = {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds
    }()


    override func loadView() {

        super.loadView()

        webViewCont = webView
        webViewCont.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height - navBarHeight - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)
        self.view.addSubview(webViewCont)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.rgb(red:255, green:255, blue:255)
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.rgb(red:230, green:32, blue:31)

        if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
            navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        }
         self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyBoardChangeNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyBoardHideNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

        callLink()

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

    }

    func callLink() {

        //Globals.activitiIndicator.showLoading()

        let urlStr:String = "https://google.com"

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        webView.load(request as URLRequest)
    }


    @objc func handleKeyBoardChangeNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {

        if let info = notification.userInfo {

            guard let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size else {
                return
            }

            self.webViewCont.frame.size.height = screenSize.height - keyboardSize.height - navBarHeight - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        }
    }

    @objc func handleKeyBoardHideNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {

        if let info = notification.userInfo {

            guard let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size else {
                return
            }

            self.webViewCont.frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

and getting error:

> ```
> 2018-02-01 19:01:24.076820+0400 IriSee[1772:742866] API error:
> <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x104fd3890; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer =
> <CALayer: 0x104fd3190>> returned 0 width, assuming
> UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric 2018-02-01 19:01:24.077076+0400
> IriSee[1772:742866] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x104fd3890;
> frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x104fd3190>> returned 0 width,
> assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric 2018-02-01 19:01:24.173133+0400
> IriSee[1772:742866] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
> satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
> following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
> constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
> the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
> don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>     "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10851d0f0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.width == UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc21b0 H:|-(8)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc2300 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676a070 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x1067695b0]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676a1c0 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x1067695b0]-(>=8)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10850c2d0 H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850b800]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10850c420 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850b800]-(>=5)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676b990 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850f680'Done']   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676bae0 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850f680'Done']-(8)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108509a00 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading ==
> _UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10.leading   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518110 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing ==
> _UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518a30 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10]-(0)-[UIView:0x10850b0e0]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518420 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x10850b0e0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1085193a0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440]-(0)-[UIView:0x10850ce20]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108519740 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x10850ce20]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108520840 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width == 0  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc1930 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint'
> H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)  
> (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc1b50 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint'
> H:[UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)  
> (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676a1c0
> H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x1067695b0]-(>=8)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2018-02-01 19:01:24.210139+0400
> IriSee[1772:742866] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
> satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
> following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
> constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
> the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
> don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>     "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10851d0f0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.width == UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc21b0 H:|-(8)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc2300 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10850c2d0 H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850b800]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10850c420 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850b800]-(>=5)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676b990 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850f680'Done']   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676bae0 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850f680'Done']-(8)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108509a00 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading ==
> _UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10.leading   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518110 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing ==
> _UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518a30 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10]-(0)-[UIView:0x10850b0e0]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518420 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x10850b0e0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1085193a0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440]-(0)-[UIView:0x10850ce20]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108519740 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x10850ce20]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108520840 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width == 0  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc1930 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint'
> H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)  
> (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc1b50 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint'
> H:[UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)  
> (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x10850c420
> H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850b800]-(>=5)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2018-02-01 19:01:24.214990+0400
> IriSee[1772:742866] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
> satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
> following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
> constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
> the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
> don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>     "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10851d0f0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.width == UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc21b0 H:|-(8)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc2300 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676b990 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850f680'Done']   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676bae0 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850f680'Done']-(8)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108509a00 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading ==
> _UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10.leading   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518110 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing ==
> _UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518a30 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10]-(0)-[UIView:0x10850b0e0]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518420 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x10850b0e0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1085193a0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440]-(0)-[UIView:0x10850ce20]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108519740 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x10850ce20]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108520840 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width == 0  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc1930 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint'
> H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)  
> (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc1b50 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint'
> H:[UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)  
> (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x10676bae0
> H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x10850f680'Done']-(8)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2018-02-01 19:01:24.219711+0400
> IriSee[1772:742866] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
> satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
> following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
> constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
> the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
> don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>     "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10851d0f0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.width == UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc21b0 H:|-(8)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc2300 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108509a00 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading ==
> _UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10.leading   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518110 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing ==
> _UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518a30 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x106768c10]-(0)-[UIView:0x10850b0e0]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108518420 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x10850b0e0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1085193a0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850b440]-(0)-[UIView:0x10850ce20]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108519740 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x10850ce20]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180]  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108520840 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width == 0  
> (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc1930 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint'
> H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)  
> (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc1b50 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint'
> H:[UILayoutGuide:0x104fc1740'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)  
> (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x108519740 'UISV-spacing'
> H:[UIView:0x10850ce20]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x10850d180]  
> (active)>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2018-02-01 19:01:24.222119+0400
> IriSee[1772:742866] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
> satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
> following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
> constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
> the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
> don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>     "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10851d0f0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.width == UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc21b0 H:|-(8)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760 )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc2300 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.trailing   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108520840 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x104fbbc90.width == 0  
> (active)>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x104fc2300
> _UIButtonBarStackView:0x104fc0500.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x104fbc760.trailing   (active)>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. willPresent notification:
> [AnyHashable("flag"): 1, AnyHashable("adtype"): 1,
> AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1517497850922445%65857e1065857e10,
> AnyHashable("adid"): 1168, AnyHashable("aps"): {
>     alert =     {
>         body = "\U10db\U10d0\U10da\U10d4!";
>         title = "\U10de\U10d8\U10ea\U10d0\U10d9\U10dd";
>     };
>     badge = 1;
>     sound = default; }]
> ```

Comment: Can you share the Apple ticket? Same problem here...

Answer (score 4):

It doesn’t look like your error. Assuming nothing untoward is happening in your interface, report it to Apple and move on.

Comment: thanks for support, reported to apple. Do you know will it effect to app submission on **appStore**?